# Symfony2/PHP: Need Image Information from image like size, height

Tags: php, symfony

I don't want to work with tempFiles in my Bundle, so I only get the content/body of the given picture in my function:

```
$pictureHandler = $this->get('picture.handler');

    $body = file_get_contents("water.jpg", "r+");

    $thumbnails = $pictureHandler->generateThumbnail($body);
```

In my generateThumbnail() function I save the given "body" in a PictureEntity.

Is it now possible to get the information of this body for example: width, height, size... ?
Because normaly you work with a complete URL to get these information. Like

```
$info = getimagesize($url);
```

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

- go for this bundle: https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle, take some time to install, configure & watch how it works;
- if you're begginer with Symfony 2, like me, and you don't have hours of learning to spend for configuring and banging your head against the wall, copy-paste my code:

(I've made an article explaining why it feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut with Symfony when you want to resize image in an Entity [here](http://www.olivierpons.fr/2014/03/22/symfony-2-avantages-et-inconvenients/) - it's in French)

```
private function resizeImage($filename, $max_width, $max_height)
{
    list($orig_width, $orig_height) = getimagesize($filename);

    $width = $orig_width;
    $height = $orig_height;

    # taller
    if ($height > $max_height) {
        $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
        $height = $max_height;
    }

    # wider
    if ($width > $max_width) {
        $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
        $width = $max_width;
    }
    $height = intval($height);
    $width = intval($width);
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    switch (exif_imagetype($filename)) {
        case 1: /* IMAGETYPE_GIF */
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            break;
        case 2: /* IMAGETYPE_JPEG */
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            break;
        case 3: /* IMAGETYPE_PNG */
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            break;
        case 4: /* IMAGETYPE_SWF */
        case 5: /* IMAGETYPE_PSD */
        case 6: /* IMAGETYPE_BMP */
        case 7: /* IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II (ordre d'octets d'Intel) */
        case 8: /* IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM (ordre d'octets Motorola) */
        case 9: /* IMAGETYPE_JPC */
        case 10: /* IMAGETYPE_JP2 */
        case 11: /* IMAGETYPE_JPX */
        case 12: /* IMAGETYPE_JB2 */
        case 13: /* IMAGETYPE_SWC */
        case 14: /* IMAGETYPE_IFF */
        case 15: /* IMAGETYPE_WBMP */
        case 16: /* IMAGETYPE_XBM */
        case 17: /* IMAGETYPE_ICO */
            throw new Exception("This kind of images is not handled");
    }
    imagecopyresampled(
        $image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height,
        $orig_width, $orig_height
    );
    return $image_p;
}
```

Comment: I like the answer, but you better use the LiipImagineBundle and take some time implementing and understanding Symfony2

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I've put it as the suggestion #1. It all depends your needs, and if the main problem is the time factor, the choose solution #2. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why would you want to resize image by private method in entity? Isn't better to create a service?

Comment: Creating a service is what I wrote: not for beginners, and if your time is priority and are a beginner, the solution #2 is faster. Not the best, but faster. In the entry of FaceBook camp there's a citation: **`done is better than perfect`**. So yes, you're right: solution #1 is the best.

Comment: Thanks, but I only want the ImageSize..! But very cool Bundle!

Comment: Any ideas on resizing LiipImagineBundle images from Javascript? Since I am using Reactjs with Symfony2, I cannot render images in twig